# How to display special characters with smarty for example '%'?

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on designing a prestashop theme, and I have a problem with the smarty template engine.

I write a text with the special character '%', but nothing is displayed.

```
<p>
  {l s='Save hundreds of hours of manual work, be more productive and impress your audience with visually appealing slides that are 100% editable.' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the HTML code for %  and use smarty pipe to escape HTML characters.

```
 {l s='Save hundreds of hours of manual work, be more productive and impress your audience with visually appealing slides that are 100&#37; editable.'|escape:'html' }
```

Answer (score 0):

thk Melvita, but I put %%.`<l s='Save hundreds of hours of manual work, be more productive and impress your audience with visually appealing slides that are 100%% editable.'>` and it works